# firebase_core throw this error when i start building the project

Tags: flutter, firebase

When I try to run the app it shows me this error:

> Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
>
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':firebase_core:compileDebugAidl'.
>
> > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':firebase_core:debugCompileClasspath'.
> > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-common:.
> > Required by:
> > project :firebase_core
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 7s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with
> exit code 1

I am using the latest version of firebase_core.

I have added Firebase to my project.

The build.gradle:

```
rootProject.ext {
    set('FlutterFire', [
            FirebaseSDKVersion: '25.12.0'
    ])
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.2.1')
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics"
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

.....

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem by deleting
the
root.text of the firebase version. It is in the
/build.gradle
and I built the project again.